# integral of function is sum of iterates

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T:X \to X$ be a measure preserving ergodic invertible transformation on a probability space.  Let $n(x)$ be the first return time to a measurable set $A$ with $\mu(A)>0$.  The task is to show that for an $f \in L^1(X)$,

$\int_X  f d \mu = \int_A \sum_{i=0}^{n(x)-1} f(T^i(x)) d \mu$

We know that by ergodicity eventually almost every point must enter A.  Hence the return time $n(x)$ is defined almost everywhere.  I'm guessing we are supposed to use some type of kakutani skyscraper argument and use that $X$ is the union of $A_n=\{n(x)=n\}$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would decompose the whole system into small brick. First if you call $B_k = n^{-1}(k)$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ you have (by Poincaré theorem):$$
A = \cup_{ k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k \text{   }mod \text{   }0
$$
Then let $B_k^j= T^{j}(B_k) $, you also have $$
X = \cup_{ k \in \mathbb{N}, j \in [0,k-1]} B_k^j \text{   }mod \text{   }0
$$
So you can decompose your integrals in this small block$$
\int_X  f d \mu = \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{N}, i \in [0,k-1]} \int_{ B_k^i} f d \mu
$$
And $$
\int_A \sum_{i=0}^{n(x)-1} f(T^i(x)) d \mu = \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{B_k}  \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} f(T^i(x)) d \mu =\sum_{ k \in \mathbb{N}, i \in [0,k-1]} \int_{B_k} f(T^i(x)) d \mu
$$
And by $T$-invariance of the measure $\mu$ $$
\int_{B_k} f(T^i(x)) d \mu = \int_{ B_k^i} f d \mu
$$
Which conclude the proof.

Comment: Why does $X=\bigcup_{i,j}B^i_k$ for $i<k$?  By ergodicity we have $X=\bigcup_i T^{-k}(A)$ but I don't see why we must have $i<k$.