# Decomposition of a space according to return time

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T: X \to X$ be an invertible measure preserving ergodic transformation on a probability space.

- Why is it that $X=\bigcup_{i,k<i}T^{-k}A_i$, where $A_i=\{n(x)=i\}$, $n(x)$ the first return map and $A$ is a set of positive measure?

From ergodicity we know that $X=\bigcup_i T^{-i}(A)$ a.e. (Which tells us that actually $n(x)$ is defined on all of $X$ mod $0$).  and  poincare recurrence theorem tells us that $A=\bigcup_k A_k$ a.e.  The problem is that I don't know why we have the stronger condition $X=\bigcup_{i,k<i}T^{-k}A_i$ with $i<k$ instead of just $X=\bigcup_{i,k}T^{-k}A_i$.

Comment: you mean "with $k<i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is False. Take a simple dynamical system made of five points $\{p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_5 \}$, with $T(p_i)= p_{i+1}$ if $i<5$ and $T(p_5)=p_1$.

We take uniform measure on this five points, of course this is an ergodic system.

Now take $A= \{p_1, p_3\}$, we have $n(p_1)=2$ and $n(p_3)=3$.
Then $$
\begin{matrix}
T^{-0}(\{p_1\})=\{p_1 \}\\
T^{-0}(\{p_3\})=\{p_3\} \\
T^{-1}(\{p_1\})=\{p_5\} \\
T^{-1}(\{p_3\})=\{p_2\} \\
T^{-2}(\{p_3\})=\{p_1\} \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Making the union of all that miss $p_4$.

Comment: Hello,  I noticed in your previous comment on my post here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290370/integral-of-function-is-sum-of-iterates/4291004#4291004  that you claimed this to be true.  Did I misinterpret something?

Comment: Never mind, it's the image not preimage.  Thanks